# AEM: tags not visible for Touh UI

Tags: tags, aem

I created content for Touch UI, uses AEM6 and create content with help with instructions http://experience-aem.blogspot.ru/2015/02/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-multi-field-component.html :

```
<categorySpotlightEntries
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
        class="full-width"
        fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
        fieldLabel="Manage Category Spotlight Items">
    <field
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
            eaem-nested=""
            name="./categorySpotlightEntries">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                method="absolute"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <tags
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete"
                            fieldLabel="Tags"
                            mode="contains"
                            multiple="{Boolean}true"
                            name="./tagField">
                        <values
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/common/autocomplete/taggingtags"/>
                        <options
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete/list"
                                src="/libs/cq/gui/content/common/tags.html{?query,start,end}"/>
                    </tags>   
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </field>
</categorySpotlightEntries>
```

All runs except Tags parameter. Tags parameter value is not saved. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: add please errors form browsers console

Comment: @cylinder.y not logs. When i moved tags blog above multifietds - it works. Maybe need specific field for tags within multifietds

Comment: try to ask on adobe forum

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a `type="select"` and/or `xtype="selection"` property on your `tags` node (although I am not familiar with using the `values` node)

Comment: You mean replace "sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete" on selection?

Comment: No, I mean new attributes in your xml for the tags node.  Look for normal dialog dropdown examples on dev.day.com

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exactly issue. it's seems that AEM save it as a "key" of a String array, but when it's load back again, he cannot "restore" the tag object, but have only a string.

see this snippets of log:

```
03.08.2016 12:22:54.053 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1470219773983] GET /content/***/it/***/***.html HTTP/1.1] com.***.core.utils.*** Unrecognized field "tags@TypeHint" (class com.***.core.models.beans.***), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: "target", "isModal", "label", "path", "tags", "buttonstyle", "linkType"])
at [Source: {"label":"***","path":"***","tags@TypeHint":"String[]","buttonstyle":"btn-secondary"}; line: 1, column: 95] (through reference chain: com.***.core.models.beans.***["tags@TypeHint"])
```

i think this issue **must** be solved by **Adobe** in nexy day i will ask to theme.